# Passing a gnuplot variable to sed in gnuplot script

Tags: sed, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script which accepts 3 command line arguments
Here is an example of command :

```
gnuplot> call BudgetRowStacked.gnu " "Fonctionnement" "2017" "545000"
```

With arguments I build a file name

```
file="Dépenses".ARG1.ARG2.".dat"
```

At the moment I use the hardcoded filename file in command such as

```
values="`sed -n -e 4p DépensesFonctionnement2017.dat`"
values2="`sed -n -e 2p DépensesFonctionnement2017.dat`"
```

I would like to use the file variable instead of the hardcoded names in the sed command. How can I do this ?

Comment: I dont'understand the similarity. I dont have a bash variable but a gnuplot variable.

Comment: Oooooh I see! That's *inside* of gnuplot. Let me retract that vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to put something like this into `BudgetRowStacked.gnu`:

```
file="Dépenses".ARG1.ARG2.".dat"

getData(fName, row)=system(sprintf("sed -n -e %dp %s", row, fName))

values = getData(file, 4)
values2 = getData(file, 2)
```

Here, `sprintf` first constructs the command of interest as a string and passes this to `system` which executes it and returns its output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I eventually  found the system command just before reading your answer. Fine !